# Getting SessionID During Socket.io Authorization?

Tags: express, session, cookies, socket.io, express-session

I'm trying to get the sessionID from express-session when a new WebSocket connection comes in from a user. I'm able to find the sessionID, I just have a question about its format.

When I make a HTTP request to my messenger page say I get 'X' as a sessionID, if I then made a WebSocket connection I can find the session ID 'AXB', the session ID X is in there, but also surrounded with other information.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var session = require('express-session');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var store = new MemoryStore({
  checkPeriod: 86400000
});

app.use(session({
  store: store,
  secret: 'jpcs-0001080900DRXPXL',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: true
}));

// ...

app.get('/messenger/:uid', authorizationRedirect, (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.sessionID);
  // prints "EIVUudPTckmojrkv6FN9Cdb5NAQq5oQU"

  // ...
});

io.set('authorization', (data, accept) => {

  if (data && data.headers && data.headers.cookie) {

    console.log(data.headers.cookie);

    cookies_str = data.headers.cookie;
    cookies_arr = cookies_str.split(';');
    cookies = {};

    for (index in cookies_arr) {
      cookie = cookies_arr[index].split('=');
      key = cookie[0].replace(/ /g,'');
      val = cookie[1];
      cookies[key] = val;
    }

    sessionId = cookies['connect.sid'].split('.')[0];
    console.log(sessionId);
    // prints "s%3AEIVUudPTckmojrkv6FN9Cdb5NAQq5oQU.AQkvP..."

    // ...

});
```

So basically, in `io.set('authorization', ...)` I get:

s%3A`EIVUudPTckmojrkv6FN9Cdb5NAQq5oQU`.AQkvPsfoxieH3EAs8laFWN28dr1C%2B9zIT%2BMXtKTRPBg

But in `app.get('/...', ...)` I get:

`EIVUudPTckmojrkv6FN9Cdb5NAQq5oQU`

You can notice that the string from socket.io does contain the session id in this format: `"s%3A" + sessionID + ".xxxxxxxxxxx..."`

So obviously I can get the sessionID from here, but I'm curious why the sessionID is shown like this when I get socket connections? Will it ALWAYS be shown like this regardless of browser, WebSocket implementations, etc? What does the other information contained mean? I mostly want to make sure that this is a reliable way to get the sessionID. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would first like to clarify that `io.set('authorization',...)` has been deprecated. Here's the updated version [Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#Authentication-differences)

> So obviously I can get the sessionID from here, but I'm curious why the sessionID is shown like this when I get socket connections? Will it ALWAYS be shown like this regardless of browser, WebSocket implementations, etc?

It's not reserved for socket connections at all. That is simply how it is fixed on the browser. So yes, it will always be shown like that.

> What does the other information contained mean? I mostly want to make sure that this is a reliable way to get the sessionID. (s%3AEIVUudPTckmojrkv6FN9Cdb5NAQq5oQU.AQkvPsfoxieH3EAs8laFWN28dr1C%2B9zIT%2BMXtKTRPBg)

The first three characters are just encoded, and I believe every sessionID containts that. `DecodedURIComponent("s%3A") = "s:"`

After that is the sessionID itself (`EIVUudPTckmojrkv6FN9Cdb5NAQq5oQU`)

Now, after the dot(`AQkvPsfoxieH3EAs8laFWN28dr1C%2B9zIT%2BMXtKTRPBg`) is the signature portion. That verifies the authenticity of the cookie and is actually given when you sign the cookie. AND yes, I would say it is a trusted and reliable way.